# AJAX call brings in multiple instance of element when I only need one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to bring in a carousel from another page but it seems to bring in 3 instances of the element that I need. I tried calling the ID and then the Class but I am still coming up short.

This the element

```
<div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel">
                <!--Slides-->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                    <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-next carousel-item-left">
                        <a href="/img/charlotteswebclose.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">

                            <img class="img-fluid" src="/img/charlotteswebclose.jpg " alt="First slide">
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item active carousel-item-left">
                        <a href="/img/charlottesweb.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="/img/charlottesweb.jpg " alt="Second slide">
                        </a>
                    </div>



                    <!--/.Slides-->

                </div>
                <!--Controls-->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                         //Press Button

                         $('#button' + index).on('click', function() {
                         $('.prodmodal').attr('id', id);
                         $('.prodmodal .modal-title').html(cardName);
                         $('.prodmodal .card_info').html(str);
                         $('#prinfo').attr('href', url);


                         $.ajax({
                         url: url,
                         success: function(result) {
                             $(".prodmodal .add_to_cart").html($(result).find('.member-div-dis'));
                             $("#pics").html($(result).find('#carousel-thumb'));
                             console.log("complete");

                         }
                        });
```

Comment: Show more code, pls.

Comment: @Tomato32 updated

Comment: Show more HTML code relates. You show more details, everyone can help you easily.

Comment: @Tomato32 here is the code